What question do participles answer?
I read in a book by Stanley Fish that a sentence is a series of relationships, and one exercise that was recommended in the book for mastering sentence construction was building up a sentence by answering questions. This, to my mind, seemed a good way to compose sentences in general. But though I can understand what question each part of speech (along with the words chosen) answers, I do not understand what a participle answers, except causation and simultaneous action.
Since participles are mostly used to signify simultaneous action, I do not know how the writing of participles can result from answering questions, because, "What was the subject or object doing at the time of the action?" is a very broad question, and does not provide specific generative power for constructing a sentence.
My question therefore is this: What questions do participles answer? And, if I am to construct a sentence by answering questions, what question will lead me to the addition of a participle to the sentence? It would seem that this part of speech is based wholly on a propositional understanding of sentences, and not on an understanding having to do with questions and answers.
I did not write this post by answering questions, but as I usually write posts.

What was the book? Doesn't it discuss the matter? Why is "What was the subject or object doing at the time of the action?" too vague? (Or more tersely "Whatcha doin'?") What sort of question is acceptably precise?

Participial clauses can answer the question "What circumstances attended this?"    "He opened the door of the mountain cabin, the blizzard swirling behind him."

'Since participles are mostly used to signify simultaneous action,' ... even if true, this presents a simplistic model which is far from being the complete picture. Anteriority ('Sitting down in his favourite armchair, he took out his pipe.') / Posteriority / Conditionality / Instrumentality / Manner / Accompanying circumstance /
Concessivity / Causation / Result  ... are possible semantic relationships. See He went into the room, opening....

Where can I read more about this?

Have you read the linked answer?

Yes. I read it yesterday. It is helpful. Thank you.

Knowing nothing about the book and having been presented with no examples of questions from the book for other sentence components, I'm somewhat guessing as to the nature of the questions you're looking for. But, let's take a shot.
The Present Participle
A participle is a verb that has been converted for use as an adjective or noun. The present participle takes the form of verb-ing. For example:

Adjective: The stumbling acrobat was funny!
Noun: His manners are the result of good breeding.

The Past Participle
The past participle can use several suffixes, though a common example is verb-ed. So, an example would be:

Adjective: The confused gentleman rose to his feet.

Some excellent examples of past-participle nouns have been provided by other users.

@AndrewLeach: The excommunicated are not allowed to join.
@PeterShor: Give me your tired, your poor. Your huddled masses yearning to breathe free, the wretched refuse of your teeming shore. Send these, the homeless, tempest-tost to me. I lift my lamp beside the golden door!

That last is from the plaque of the U.S. Statue of Liberty. It uses one past-participle adjective (huddled, note that "wretched" is the declination of a noun and is not a participle), one present-participle adjective (teeming), and one past-participle noun (tost). Tost is an archaic past-tense of "to toss" and, as @Lambie points out, would today be written "tossed."
Other participle tenses follow the same patterns. They'll be verbs used as adjectives or nouns.
Constructing Sentences
The adjective form of the participle is the simplest to work with. You can ask...

What is the subject/object doing? (is stumbling, became confused)

The noun form is a bit more difficult to ask about, because the noun is, itself, an object. I hope you'll agree with me that the previous question doesn't quite work with my noun example. (What were the manners doing? Certainly not breeding.) So perhaps the question could be...

Is this noun created from a verb?

If that's acceptable in the context of your book, then it could be used for both types of participle.

Is this noun/adjective created from a verb?

If it's not acceptable or doesn't help you, then we need examples from your book to guide us.

You can construct a sentence with a past participle as a noun, such as "The excommunicated are not allowed to join." I wonder if there's a question about which verbs function well in this usage.

@AndrewLeach Yes, certainly you can construct a sentence with a participle as the head of the clausal subject, but under most analyses it’s still an adjective, not a noun. Syntactic evidence for this includes that it’s modifiable by adverbs like recently not by adjectives like recent, plus isn’t morphologically plural nor can be made so—unlike givens or fixings. The simplest explanation is probably the one where it’s all that’s left over from an elided plural noun like people or things. Terminology ranges from OED’s “absolute adjectives” to CGEL’s “fused modifier-head NPs”.
